# Do I need to nest an input text into a flex div to make it resizable? One method is working, the other is not

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've made 2 examples on codepen you can check.

Working: https://codepen.io/atr00/pen/VwGQyeg?editors=1100

```
.inner-content {
  border: 2px dashed orange;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  min-width: 0px;
  width: 600px;
}

<div class="content">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-content">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="inner-content">
    <input type="text">
  </div>    
</div>
```

not working: https://codepen.io/atr00/pen/wvEyyBq?editors=1100

```
input {
  min-width: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px dashed orange;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  
}

<div class="content">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

content is common to both:

```
.content {
  border: 2px solid green;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

In the first example, I've nested a row flex into the column flex and it's correctly resizing the input text.
My guess is that the second example has the input text into a column flex and therefore it's not resizing the width of the input text. However, I've defined the input in the exact same way at the row flex.
I am not sure I fully grasp the difference between the 2 methods.

Does anyone have a clear explanation of what's happening?

Thanks!

Trying to resize on the width.
Example 1 properly resizes the input text, example 2 overflows its container.

Comment: Try setting `width: min(600px, 100%);` on the `input` in your second example. The reason the inputs overflow is just because they have a fixed width (and the parent flexbox doesn't have influence on that, because it's a column flexbox). As a sidenote, setting `display: flex;` on the `input` is probably not what you want, since it cannot contain any children.

Comment: thanks, it worked! I thought this issue would be taken care of by `min-width: 0px;`
In your opinion, which is the best solution between the 2?

Comment: I generally try to avoid additional non-semantic HTML elements, so I'd go for #2. It keeps your HTML clean, and puts your CSS in control of the styling completely.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by `vrugtehagel` above worked.

> Try setting width: `min(600px, 100%);` on the input in your second example. The reason the inputs overflow is just because they have a fixed width (and the parent flexbox doesn't have influence on that, because it's a column flexbox).